# For XML multiple subsection

Tags: sql, xml, relationship

Quick question for all the gurus out there.

I am trying to pull data out of a table in an XML format that has a subsection with multiple data. It is a list of managers with their employees. Think of like an organizational chart. It is all coming out of one table that looks like this:

```
| ManagerID| EmployeeID |
|     0049 |    4433    |
|     0049 |    4430    |
```

I need this:

```
<manager>
  <id>0049</id>
  <name>John Doe</name>
  <employees>
    <employee>
      <id>4433</id>
    </employee>
    <employee>
      <id>4430</id>
    </employee>
  </employees>
</manager>
```

I've tried writing some simple queries that I found on here. However, since the number of  can be high, its not working right. I am getting multiple  records for the same manager.

I only need 1 per manager. What is the proper query?

Comment: Where does the manager name come from? What would the resulting XML look like if you have more than two levels? What DBMS is this for

Answer (score 0):

I don't like hierarchical SQL queries, yes they are supported by many SQL databases, but I like in memory post processing, since it is really simple and straight forward, and what is more important, you can easily improve and fix bugs in your data.

Here is what you have to approximately do, the following example is in PHP
It reads the same Manager->Employee relationships and export the whole hierarchy into JSON object.

In your case you have to serialize final object into XML instead of JSON.

```
// Connect to your Database 
mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error()); 

// Select accounts
$response = mysql_query("SELECT EmployeeID as id, ManagerID as parentid, name, title, description, phone, email, photo FROM accounts") or die(mysql_error()); 

// create some class for your records
class Account
{
    public $id = 0;
    public $parentid = null;
    public $name = '';
    public $title = '';
    public $desciption = '';
    public $phone = '';
    public $email = '';
    public $photo = '';

    public $children = array();

    public function load($record) {
        $this->id = intval($record['record_id']);
        $this->parentid = intval($record['parentid']);
        $this->title = $record['title'];
        $this->name = $record['name'];
        $this->description = $record['description'];
        $this->phone = $record['phone'];
        $this->email = $record['email'];
        $this->photo = $record['photo'];
    } 
}

// create hash and group all children by parentid
$children = Array();
while($record = mysql_fetch_array( $response )) 
{ 
    $account = new Account();
    $account->load($record);

    if( !isset($children[$account->parentid])) {
        $children[$account->parentid] = array();
    }
    array_push($children[$account->parentid], $account);
} 

// Create hierarchical structure starting from  $rootAccount
function recursiveLoadChildren($parent, $children) {
    if(isset($children[$parent->id])) {
        foreach($children[$parent->id] as $id => $account) {
            array_push($parent->children, $account);
            recursiveLoadChildren($account, $children);
        }
    }
}

$rootAccount = $children[0][0];
recursiveLoadChildren($rootAccount, $children);    

// serialize $rootAccount object including all its children into JSON string  
$jsonstring = json_encode($rootAccount);
```